# Implementing ERGMs with PyMC

Tags: python, pymc3, pymc

I am trying to implement ERGMs with PyMC.


I've found [this](https://socialabstractions-blog.tumblr.com/post/53391947460/exponential-random-graph-models-in-python), [this](https://gist.github.com/dmasad/78cb940de103edbee699), [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-bayesian-logistic-regression-with-python-and-pymc3-4dd463bbb16) and [this](https://computational-communication.com/forum/ergm-python/), but these resources are a bit dated.

I have an NxN matrix for each network statistic (`density`, `triangles`, `istar2`, `istar3` & `distance`). Each cell in each matrix indicates how the presence of that potential edge would change that statistic, holding the rest of the network constant. `am` is the adjacency matrix of graph `G` (`nx.to_numpy_array(G)`).


My model looks like this.

```py
with pm.Model() as model:

    density = pm.ConstantData("density", density)
    triangles = pm.ConstantData("triangles", triangles)
    istar2 = pm.ConstantData("istar2", istar2)
    istar3 = pm.ConstantData("istar3", istar3)
    distance = pm.ConstantData("distance", distance)

    β_density = pm.Normal('β_density', mu=0, sigma=100)
    β_triangles = pm.Normal('β_triangles', mu=0, sigma=100)
    β_istar2 = pm.Normal('β_istar2', mu=0, sigma=100)
    β_istar3 = pm.Normal('β_istar3', mu=0, sigma=100)
    β_distance = pm.Normal('β_distance', mu=0, sigma=100)

    μ = β_density*density + β_triangles*triangles + β_istar2*istar2 + β_istar3*istar3 + β_distance*distance
    θ = pm.Deterministic('θ', pm.math.sigmoid(μ))
    
    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=θ, observed=am)

    trace=pm.sample(
        draws=500, 
        tune=1000,
        cores=1,
    )
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: What's going on here: `y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=θ, observed=y)`? I.e., what is `y` before this? Either way, maybe try sampling with Metropolis steps, just to see if it runs correctly, then I'd probably do VI instead of NUTS.

Comment: @merv Sorry for the omission, I edited the question. `y` is the adjacency matrix of the graph.

Comment: My concern is that `y` is on both LHS and RHS.

Comment: @merv Thank you for your suggestions! In the full version of my code the `y` is actually `am`. I have edited the code to reflect that.